# Angular 2 custom directive bind property through method unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a custom directive with few input properties have bind values to them. I tried to bind one of the property via method as follows. But it is calling multiple times when the parent component load or do any changes on the parent component.
My directive is as follows

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-error]', exportAs: 'my-error',
  providers: []
})

export class UsErrorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() errorMsg: string;

  private displayError: boolean;

  @Input('displayError') set $displayError(value: boolean) {
    this.displayError = value;
    if (this.displayError) {
       console.log("Display error")
    } else {
       console.log("Close Display error")
    }
  }
  @Input() placement: 'top' | 'bottom' | 'left' | 'right';

}
```

Parent component HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="name" class="control-label required">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" formControlName="name" my-error [displayError]="isFieldValid('name')" [errorMsg]="formErrors.name"
          placement="right">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="email" class="control-label required">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" my-error [displayError]="isFieldValid('email')"
          [errorMsg]="formErrors.email" placement="right">

      </div>
    </div>
```

Component.ts **isFieldValid** method as follows

```
isFieldValid(field: string) {
    console.log(field);
    return !this.myForm.get(field).valid && this.myForm.get(field).touched;
  }
```

My issue is **isFieldValid** is calling multiple times unexpectedly.

Comment: its is down to the `changedetectionstrategy` of Angular and this is the expected behaviour